Looking for an efficient indexed data structure supporting random access and deletion
I think I have stumbled upon a novel data structure.
Does there exist one where i can add and delete elements at a particular index, both efficiently (better than linear time)? It is not a requirement that the elements in the structure be indexed by their order. For example, elements can be stored as 5, 2, 8, 1, 3, 3. DataStructure[2] will give 8 and del DataStructure[2] will delete 8.

A balanced binary search tree that has elements implicitly keyed on its index in the data structure (by storing the subtree size in each node) supports insertion and deletion at arbitrary indexes in O(log(N)) as part of its basic operations.
This data structure can also be augmented for queries on subarrays, including range sum, range maximum, range add, range set, and range reverse.

In short, this data structure is not new.

U mean I can add an element, say 8, at any index in the structure? If so, how would I go on about doing that? Thanks

@GursimarSinghMiglani Split the data structure at that index, then merge the new item in. Split and merge can both be done in O(log(N)).

What exactly do you mean by split and merge?

@GursimarSinghMiglani For instance, you can easily divide a splay tree into two trees, one with all keys <= k (implicit key) and one with all keys > k. Merge is the opposite operation.

so lets say i wanted to add 8 at index k. i would split the tree in two at index k, and then what? combine the trees back? i don't know what you are implying. A link to the concept would be helpful

@GursimarSinghMiglani Yes, merging means combining the trees back (in order). What method of supporting these operations did you have in mind?

do we sort the keys by their index? if so, how do we shift the indices of the elements after the index k by 1? isnt that linear time?

@GursimarSinghMiglani We are not shifting anything. One way to do this in amortized time is with a splay tree. Do you understand how splay trees work? Split and merge (join) are basic operations with a splay tree.

ok ill look into it

I think there're no data structures where you can add and delete elements at a particular index, both efficiently (better than linear time). Below is some popular data structures:
1. Array/Vector:

Insert and delete: O(n)
Random access: O(1)
So the time complexity of insert and delete elements at a particular index is O(1)+O(n)=O(n).

2. Linked list:

Insert and delete: O(1)
Random access: O(n)
So the time complexity of insert and delete elements at a particular index is O(n)+O(1)=O(n) too.

3. Set:

Ordered set: You can only store array of sorted and unique numbers (like [1,2,3,5,8], not [5,2,8,1,3,3]).
Unordered set: You can't store the order of numbers in the array.

4. Map:

Ordered map: Insert and delete: O(log(n)) and Random access at index k: O(k*log(n)). If you have a ordered map with float as key, for example: {1.0:5, 2.0:2, 3.0:8, 4.0:1, 5.0:3, 6.0:3}, and you want to insert 10 to element at index k (cost O(log(n)), you can insert {k_index:10} to the map, with k_index is a number between the key of element index k-1 and index k (cost O(k*log(n)). Total time complexity: O(k*log(n)). If k < n/log(n) or k << n then the time complexity will be better than O(n).
Unordered map: Insert and delete: O(1) and Random access: O(n*log(n)) (you have to short the elements of unorder map by index (cost O(n*log(n)) before be able to random access). Like ordered map, but total time complexity is O(n*log(n)).


Looks like good news to me :p

Except that it is not true.
